# Sum up a value in Json row inside PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Suppose I have a table in PostgreSQL that has two column, Id and Doc.
In the Doc column a Json object like below:

```
{"eid":{"a":5, "b":6, "c":9}, "time":12345}
{"eid":{"b":6, "c":9, "x":25}, "time":13255}
```

I would be appreciate to help me to write a query which sums up 'a' eids according to specified time.
Thanks

Comment: The nearest thing that i could do is: `select json_each(events.doc->'eid') from events` that produced **records** like **('a',5)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unsure what you mean by "according to specified time", but I think you want :

```
SELECT * FROM j;
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                        doc                        │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ {"eid": {"a": 5, "b": 6, "c": 9}, "time": 12345}  │
│ {"eid": {"b": 6, "c": 9, "x": 25}, "time": 13255} │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(2 rows)

SELECT SUM((doc#>>'{eid,a}')::integer) 
FROM j 
WHERE (doc->>'time')::integer = 12345;
┌─────┐
│ sum │
├─────┤
│   5 │
└─────┘
(1 row)
```

---

**EDIT**

To get all the keys at once (you might need to change `jsonb_*` to `json_*` depending on your schema) :

```
SELECT key, SUM(jsonb_extract_path_text(doc, 'eid', key)::integer)
FROM j, jsonb_object_keys(doc->'eid') sub(key)
GROUP BY key
;
┌─────┬─────┐
│ key │ sum │
├─────┼─────┤
│ x   │  25 │
│ b   │  12 │
│ a   │   5 │
│ c   │  18 │
└─────┴─────┘
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marth, if i want to have a result that each eid is sumed in a row (like **<'a',5>, <'b',12>, <'c', 18> and <'x', 25>** ), what should I do?

Comment: @ehsantoghian : edited my answer. However I'm unsure of how you intend to use the `time` value in this query, since it seems you want to take all `eid`s at once.

Comment: Thanks @Marth, the time is used when i want to confine the output events (**eid**) to a period of time. For example i want to see the event between 9 AM and 5 PM.

Answer (score 1):

To sum all values of array `eid` for a given `time` use this query:

```
select time, sum(value)
from (
    select
        (json_each(doc->'eid')).value::text::int,
        doc->>'time' as time
    from events 
    ) alias
group by 1
order by 1
```